# Can't install Packages in Julia

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

As the title says I can't seem to be able to install packages in Julia using Pluto anymore even though until a few days ago everything worked as it should.[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxKkc.png)
[image: New Error]

Answer (score 3):

These are indeed some of the more tricky situations to resolve so please bear with me as we work through this.

1. I would first suggest that you switch over from Pluto to the Julia Repl (the command-line version of Julia) as it makes running the Pkg command much easier. You can run by typing `julia` in the terminal or by opening the julia "desktop app" downloaded from https://julialang.org.
2. If you are not familiar with the basics of the package manager, it's worth a quick read to check out: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/getting-started/
3. Assuming you are now in the Julia Repl, my general work flow for these issues is to remove everything it warns me about. The core problem here is that one of your existing packages is saying it needs a specific version of Distributions.jl but it's not able to add it. So, the first step would be to enter the pkg manager by doing `]` and type `rm Distributions`.
4. Then, while still in the pkg mode, do `resolve` and `add Distributions`.

Let me know if you still run into the issue after that (please edit your original question with the updated info).

Comment: Thank you for your help but there still is an error.
I added the new image to my original question.

Comment: So the process is to just remove each package the Repl complains about until it stops complaining. So in this case, `rm CUDA` and repeat for any other packages it complains about. Can you also do a `registry status` command to make sure you are still connected to the general julia registry?

Comment: Thanks, I just completely removed Julia and started reinstalling the packages and that seems to have worked.

But thank you for your fast answers :)

Comment: If you run into something like this again, the worst-case scenario is to remove the project and manifest files for the specific Julia version you are using. If you navigate to ".julia/environments" you should be able to completely reset the Julia Env for a specific version there (that way you don't need to actually reinstall Julia).